# How do I change this function from two returns to one string to show sku and dimensions in WooCommerce cart?

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic

We are developing a B2B shop with WooCommerce.

I want to show the SKU and the product dimensions underneath the product title in the cart.

This is what I have right now:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'add_sku_in_cart', 20, 3);
function add_sku_in_cart( $title, $values, $cart_item_key ) {
$sku = $values['data']->get_sku();
$dimensions = $values['data']->get_dimensions();
return $sku ? $title . sprintf(" <br><span class='articlenumber'>Artikelnummer: %s</span>", $sku) : $title;
return $dimensions ? $title . sprintf(" <br><span class='measurements'>Maße: %s</span>", $dimensions) : $title;
}
```

Someone already told me that 2 returns won´t work and that I need a string. But since I am very new to PHP, I don´t know how to do it. Could someone please help me with that?

Thank you in advance and have a great day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `function` in PHP can have 0 or 1 `return` statement. It is important to know that a `return` will also end the execution of a function. You can read more about that in [the official PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php). For the other part, you need to make one string out of multiple strings, this is called concatenation and already used in your code, [read more about it here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

Applying those principles (and using proper `if` instead of ternary for better readability), your code turns into:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'add_sku_in_cart', 20, 3);
function add_sku_in_cart( $title, $values, $cart_item_key ) {
    $sku = $values['data']->get_sku();
    $dimensions = $values['data']->get_dimensions();
    if ($sku) {
        $title = $title . sprintf(" <br><span class='articlenumber'>Artikelnummer: %s</span>", $sku);
    }
    if ($dimensions) {
        $title = $title . sprintf(" <br><span class='measurements'>Maße: %s</span>", $dimensions);
    }
    return $title;
}
```

Comment: This code gives me some errors, VSC is pointing out `$title = $title . sprintf(" <br><span class='articlenumber'>Artikelnummer: %s</span>", $sku) : $title;` and `$title = $title . . sprintf(" <br><span class='measurements'>Maße: %s</span>", $dimensions) : $title;` as source of the error.

In short: It unfortunately doesn´t work.

Comment: @MarvinKlempert Sorry, copy/paste errors. Should work now, I forgot to remove these parts of the ternary (`foo ? a : b`) when changing to long `if`

Comment: This was it. Now the code works. Thank you very much. I will be doing a basic php course soon, so I really understand the basics.